# How to pass data/information between different forms on diffrent pages in Symfony 3?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am working on a rather simple task in a `Symfony 3.4` based project but I struggle to solve it. This is about a two-step deletion process. One page/form to select a list of entities for deletion and another page/form to ask for confirmation:

- `example.com/delete` presents a form which holds a list of entities which can be selected for deletion.
- When the form is submitted corresponding controller is called, the form handled to get the selected entities. The controller preforms some checks to filter out entities which cannot be deleted for some reason.
- Now the entities should **NOT** be deleted directly. Instead the users should redirected to `example.com/delete_confirm` where deletion of the selected entities has to be confirmed.
- If deletion is confirmed the `example.com/delete_confirm` controller is called actually perform the deletion.

Of course I could use other methods like a JS dialog on `example.com/delete` to ask for confirmation but for several reasons I would prefer the described two-step process. On reason is that I need the to check the selected entities first.

**Question is, if/how this two-step process can be implemented.**

---

### Details

The `deleteAction` controller is responsible to create and handle the form which allows to select the entities for deletion. How can this controller pass the selected entities to the `deleteConfirmAction` controller?

```
class DeletionController {
    public function deleteAction(Request request) {
        $entities = $this->loadEntitiesFromDB();        

        $form = $this->creatFormBuilder()
            ->add('entities', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'AppBundle:TheEntity',
                'choices' => $entities,                 
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
            ])
            ->getForm();

         $form->handleRequest($request);
         if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
             $entities = $form->getData();

             // Handle / filter / change / check the submitted entites
             $checkedEntites = $this->checkEntitesToDelete(entities);

             // How to re-direct to the confirmation page INCLUDING the entities?
             ...?

             return $this->redirectToRoute('delete_confirm_route', $checkedEntites);
         }

         return $this->render('AppBundle::delete.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
    }



    public function deleteConfirmAction(Request request) {
        $entities = $this->loadEntitiesFromDB();        

        $confirmationForm = $this->creatFormBuilder()
            ->add(Add the entities to the form, e.g. as ID list of hidden fields)
            ->getForm();

         $confirmationForm->handleRequest($request);
         if ($confirmationForm->isSubmitted() && $confirmationForm->isValid()) {
             $entityIDs = $confirmationForm->getData();

             // Perform deletion
             $this->deleteEntities($entityIDs);

             // Re-direct back to deletion page to select other entities
             return $this->redirectToRoute("delete_route");
         }

         return $this->render('AppBundle::delete_confirm.html.twig', ['form' => $confirmationForm->createView()]);
    }
}
```

**Problems:**

- Redirecting **the submitted entities** to the confirmation page using `$this->redirectToRoute('delete_confirm_route', $checkedEntites)` does not work of course.
- While it would be possible to send a list of entity ids as query parameters this would be a quite ugly solution and the length of the query string is limited

**How to solve this? Is it even possible?**

Comment: Why does redirectToRoute does not work?

Comment: Of course the re-direct it self would work, but including the `$checkedEntites` as data / information would not.

Comment: return $this->redirectToRoute('delete_confirm_route', ['ids' => ['1', '2', '3', ...]]); should indeed work ...

Comment: Sure, but as said in the question: *"While it would be possible to send a list of entity ids as query parameters this would be a quite ugly solution and the length of the query string is limited"*

Comment: So, how do you normally transfer data to a controller? The solution isn't ugly but maybe the http method not really the most suitable. What about using post data?

Comment: you could set a flag on the entities that they are marked for deletion. if the user confirms -> delete marked entities; if the user declines -> remove flag

Comment: Oddly similar to a question asked yesterday.  Just kidding. Store the id's in your session.

Comment: @Cerad I don't think storing it inside session is a good idea because it doesn't respect purpose of session itself. It is not ugly at all to pass list of ids as parameters, and it is the most appropriate way for me.

Comment: @JessGabriel I suppose we could get into an off-topic discussion of why storing session data in the session does not respect the purpose of a session.  But before we do that, explain what would prevent the user from adding or changing the id's using your methodology.